# Spring 3 mvc - using @component @Value to read properties from a file is not working if class is not injected by Spring DI

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, components

I have to implement a Web service in spring mvc 3.0 which has a callbackhandler class to get the password, currently i am setting the hardcoded password value instead i want to get it from properties file. I tried @component and @value it didn't work, because the Callback class was not injected by spring DI.

refer the below code snippet i was using the @Value annotation in calss ComPropScan to fetch the properties value. @Autowired this class in TestComPropscan class it didn't work. 
                i have instantiated class TestComPropscan in service layer LoginServiceImpl.java.
                The TestComPropscan calss has @component and @value to fetch the properties, when i debug the value of scanprop is null.

is using Resource bundle in such scenario correct in spring? 
I am not using spring-security jars. Any suggestion would help.
The webservice call is done using CFX 2.

servlet-context.xml

```
    <beans ........>
      <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.libapp.controller, com.libapp.service, com.libapp.readprop"/>

     <context:property-placeholder
            location="file:${catalina.base}/conf/environment.properties" />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

LoginService.java

```
        package com.libapp.service;

        public interface LoginService {
        public boolean validate(String userName, String password);
        }
```

Below is LogingServiceImpl.java - service implementation layer

```
    package com.libapp.service.impl;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.libapp.readprop.CallbackClass;
    import com.libapp.readprop.TestComPropscan;
    import com.libapp.service.*;

    @Service
    public class LoginImpl implements LoginService{


        public boolean validate(String userName, String password) {
            if(userName != null && userName.equals("test") && password!=null && password.equals("test"))
            {
                TestComPropscan test = new TestComPropscan();
                test.printScanProp();
                System.out.println("Validate method of test loginimpl");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for   TestComProscan.java

```
  package com.libapp.readprop;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

            import utils.CompPropScan;
            @Component
            public class TestComPropscan {

                @Autowired
                private CompPropScan scanprop;

                public void printScanProp()
                {
                    System.out.println(TestComPropscan.class.getName()+" ======= "+scanprop.getuserId());
                }
            }
```

Below is the controller class          /*    controller class */

```
 package com.libapp.controller;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

            import com.libapp.service.LoginService;

            @Controller
            public class LoginController {

                @Autowired
                private LoginService loginService;

                @RequestMapping("/login")
                public ModelAndView loginentry()
                {
                    String msg = "Welcome to LibApp";
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    return new ModelAndView("login","message",msg);
                }
                @RequestMapping(value="/validate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
                public ModelAndView validateUser(@RequestParam("username") String userName,@RequestParam("passwd") String password)
                {
                    ModelAndView validateview = new ModelAndView();
                    validateview.setViewName("welcome");
                    System.out.println("inside validate url method");
                    //ValdiateLoginImpl validateUser= new ValdiateLoginImpl();
                    boolean isAuthorized = loginService.validate(userName, password);
                    //System.out.println(userName+" && "+password);
                    if(isAuthorized)
                    {   String message = "Successfuly logged in...";
                        return validateview.addObject("message", message);
                    }
                    else{   String message = "Failed to logged in...";
                        return validateview.addObject("message",message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Class where @value used

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class CompPropScan  {

    @Value("user.id")
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly i don't saw the place where you are trying use the annotation @Value and this is not a erro, for you get the property value in your class, you will need to put the class in your application context or pass the property by reference.

Comment: Hi i missed pasting that class in first place. The @value annotation was used in a separate class with getter setter method

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what @Tiarê Balbi was saying, the actual problem that you are having is that Spring is unable to determine that your `@Value` annotation exists on that class, because Spring doesn't actually know the class exists.

As you've discovered if you annotate the class with `@Component` or a similar annotation this still isn't going to work. Even though this will register the class with the Spring's Application Context, it won't have the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` run over it, which is the class that processes `@Value` annotations. As its name suggests it performs post-processing on autowired beans. This process is explained on the [Spring API for the `@Value` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html?is-external=true)

Make sure you have correct syntax for your `@Value` annotation. I've missed a closing `}` a few times and spent an hour scratching my head trying to figure out what was wrong.

```
@Value("${external.property.name}")
```

TL;DR: Its impossible to use `@Value` on a class that is not `@Autowired` because the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` will not pass over the class to process the `@Value` annotations.

If it is still unclear what is going on, tell me and I will expand.

Comment: thanks for the input i can follow your point. i wanted to simulate a situation faced in my application and the above code snippet is the same. i am implementing a web service call, (CFX) where there is a callbackhandler class is called by the interceptor of WSS4jOutInterceptor. The callbackhandler class has the hardcoded password string. i wanted to read that value from the password. The CFX jar will instantiate that callbackhandler class which means not DI (not injected by Spring). Even in the simulated code able, the TestComPropscan class is instantiated within the LoginImpl (service layer).

Comment: So which class can't you autowire and why?

Comment: In the above code snippet, when i debug and when the code flow passes into 
TestComPropscan test = new TestComPropscan();
test.printScanProp();
it threw null pointer exception. as printScanProp() method prints the userid which is set in the CompScan class.

Comment: You've got a design issue then. You would need to change your application design to allow the callback handler class to be autowired by Spring

Comment: Yep, if you try to read the value of the password variable and you've annotated  with `@Value` but aren't autowiring the callback handler class , then password will be null

Comment: yes that can be done using spring-security framework, where we can create a bean for callbackhandler in application context xml. but i don't want to use spring security for this.
here in the above code in service layer i have explicitly instantiated the TestComProScan class which had the value annotation of properties file. if i did a autowire to TestComProScan then the value gets printed correctly.